# Delete row from a table after some time

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table for messages, in the system when the user reads the message system will add the read time into the database, I want to delete the message after 1 day from readTime but i cannot manage it on asp.net part. How can ı handle that situation on cs part or database(Triggers vs.)

My Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Message] (
[messageID]      INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[ToUserId]       NVARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
[FromUserId]     NVARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
[messageContent] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[isRead]         INT            NOT NULL,
[sendingTime]    DATETIME       NOT NULL,
[readingTime]    DATETIME       NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([messageID] ASC),
FOREIGN KEY ([FromUserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserID]),
FOREIGN KEY ([ToUserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserID])
```

);

my code

```
string readDate = "";
    String CS2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StegoDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(CS2);
    using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select * FROM Message WHERE messageID='" + messageID + "'and isRead=1 ", con2))
    {
        con2.Open(); 
         SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            readDate = dt.Rows[0]["readingTime"].ToString();
            DateTime rDate = Convert.ToDateTime(readDate);
            DateTime cDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now);
            TimeSpan ts = cDate - rDate;
            int days= ts.Days;
            if (days > 1) //
            {
                String CS1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StegoDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(CS1);
                using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("delete * FROM Message WHERE messageID='" + messageID + "' ", con1))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1))
                    {
                        con1.Open();
                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Job that runs for example once a day that will find and delete all messages older than ... or simple expiration date column and application that will not show expired messages.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  You say you want to delete from "messages", but you show a table called "users".  You say you want to use `ReadTime`, but the table only has `BlockedTime`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry for wrong copy ı fixed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete the message at leisure . . . if ever.

Let me assume a reasonable interpretation of your question that involves a table called `messages`, not `users`.  Use a view on the table:

```
create view v_messages as 
    select m.*
    from messages m
    where m.readtime > dateadd(day, -1, getdate());
```

If you use the view for accessing the table, you never have to worry about seeing old messages.  In fact, you can leave them there forever.   Further, you can arrange permissions on the table so users only have access to the view and not to the underlying table, providing additional protection.

Let me add that the date/time values should be added by the *database*, not the *application*.  This is particularly important in a real-world application with multiple users.  You have no control over the clocks on their computers.

Then, if you really do want to delete the messages, you can schedule a job to run once a day or once a week or whenever to delete old messages in the database.

Do note that deleting things from a table can be an expensive process -- locking down rows, pages, indexes, and maybe the entire table.  You would normally want to do this at a relatively quiet time.